# async.eachSeries RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cryptojs

I am running this on node.js v0.10.33 with async@0.9.0 trying to test `crypto.createCipher` but end up getting error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
/**
 * New node file
 */
var crypto = require('crypto');
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('underscore');

var l = [];
var o = [];
for (var i=0; i<4899; i++) {
    l.push(String(i));
}

var key = 'mykey';
var algorithm = 'aes256';

async.eachSeries(l, function(item, callback) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(item, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
    o.push(encrypted);
    callback(null);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('err', err, 'o', o.length, 'o-uniq', _.uniq(o).length)
    var le = _.map(o, function(i) {
        return i.length
    })
    console.log('le', le.length, 'le-uniq', _.uniq(le).length, le[0])
})
```

Error stack:

```
node.js:896
    var fn = runInThisContext(source, this.filename, true);
             ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: why are you using async library to call sync functions in a loop? or am i missing something?

Comment: good point, i thought about it just now. I didn't realize crypto.createcipher is synchronous. anyways, i guess, the right way to do it would be using a simple for loop